# How to log in programmatically to a web page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need some help to post username and password to a web page and then invoke the click event for the log in.
In order to better understand what I'm trying to do, a good example could be the following one:

programmatically send to a bank account's web page username and password (in the relevant inputs) and then, once logged in, retrieve the balance.

This means that in my app I'll have a XAML page with 2 textboxes, 1 button and 1 textblock.

Parse a site is quite easy, so that I'd be able to get the balance but I can't send the data to the server for the log in.
I've already read several examples with WP8 but none of them allows me to understand how to proceed with WP8.1 where, apparently, things are little bit different.

I've tried with this code where I assumed the inputs are called "user" and "password":

```
    private async void LogIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://www.something.com";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        string postData = "user=" + textBoxUser.Text + "&password=" + textBoxPassword.Text;

        byte[] send = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        Stream sout = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
        sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
        sout.Dispose();

        var myHttpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        var response = await myHttpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var dataBack = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //Debug:
        Debug.WriteLine(dataBack);
    }
```

Even though I don't receive any error, the inputs in the response are empty and moreover I don't know how to invoke the click event of the button in the web page to submit the data.

In addition, I don't want to open the web page since everything would be managed by the 4 controls of the app.

Is there anybody who can give some suggestion or address me where I can find something which suits my need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're already on the right path: putting together the correct `POST` request the way a browser would send it after the user submits the form.

You may however need to set `Referer` parameters and maybe a CSRF token or such in addition to naming the parameters correctly. The best approach would be to submit the form in an actual browser and look at the request that it sends via the built-in developer tools, then reverse-engineer that one from within your app.

Comment: Hello ma_il, thanks for your suggestion.
I didn't think to check how a browser performs a POST request. This is really a good idea and Firebug will be my friend for such a thing. Setting referrer parameters and cross-site request will be little tricky but I'll keep trying.